# I don't have a file defined for Assetic, but it still get loaded

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I have a js file that I took out of any Assetic definitions, but it still gets loaded by Assetic.  I tried clearing the cache, and I even changed the filename.  What's going on here?

Comment: try clearing your cache for both environments, and run `app/console assetic:dump` if you're using named assets. And clear your browser's cache also.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there are assets used in vendor templates, try to check your installed vendors.